# multithreading log printing prioriry c++

Tags: c++

in multithreading how can I give priority for printing log based on severity? for example, if I have a multithreaded program of printing log and the program printing 3 severities to log: debug, error and fatal. 
if fatal come along with error, fatal should appear first, error 2nd.
how can I achieve the above?

Comment: Assuming that you log things as soon as possible you can't. Otherwise you can store things that should be logged later somewhere using a lock and then go through them afterwards with whatever priority you want

Comment: How would you want to detect that multiple log requests come in exactly the same time?

Comment: You could use separate queues for each severity. If the "fatal" queue is empty go to the "error" queue, and if it's empty then go on to the "debug" queue", and if it's also empty then there's nothing to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a thread to print the log.

Use a [priority queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) to feed data from the other threads (that generate log events) to the logging thread. Protect the priority queue with a mutex, so only one thread can modify it at a time.

Use the severity level as the primary key, and the timestamp as the secondary key determining the queue's priority. Note that by default, a priority queue orders keys so the *largest* comes first--you may have to specify `std::greater<T>` to do the equivalent of a descending sort to get the right order if `fatal` is 0, `error` is 1, an `debug` is 2 (and you'll definitely want a descending comparison for the time-stamps).

This way, a fatal error will move directly to the front of the queue, but if you have (for example) three Warnings that show up near the same time, they'll all stay ordered by time.